# Uniquely identify Javascript Modal in PHP while loop

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I've got a while loop in PHP which results several rows of a database table. I also have an amend button next to each row which prompts Javascript to display a Modal in a div.

The button ID is 'amend' and the Modal ID is 'modal'. These elements are identified using getElementbyID.

I know that these elements need to be unique so that all of the amend buttons opens the correct Modal. I've but my code down below which works only for the first row of the while loop result. I've also provided my unsuccessful attempt to make this elements unique using PHP variables.

```
<button id="amend" value="<?php echo $opRow['group_id']; ?>">Amend/button>

<div id="modal" class="modal">
modal info comes here and I use <?php opRow[''] ?> to display info relating to the row which has been selected
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript I'm using.

```
<script>

var modal = document.getElementById("modal");


var btn = document.getElementById("amend");


var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}


span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried in the Javascript to put my PHP in (like below) and concat the words amend and modal but this has not worked!

```
var modal = document.getElementById(<?php  ?>);
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Are you open to using jQuery?

Comment: @PatrickQ of course!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something other that `id` to identify multiple elements. The method `document.getElementById()` will only return the first element with that `id`, since the `id` attribute should be unique to the page.

If, instead, you output you HTML like:

```
<button class="amend" value="<?php echo $opRow['group_id']; ?>">Amend/button>

<div class="modal" data-group="<?php echo $opRow['group_id']; ?>">
modal info comes here and I use <?php opRow[''] ?> to display info relating to the row which has been selected
</div>
```

You could then select your elements with the following:

```
<script>
document.querySelectorAll(".amend").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var modelTarget = event.target.value;
    document.querySelector('[data-group="' + modelTarget + '"]').style.display = "block";
});

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

This makes things generic enough that it should work with as many `.amend` and `.modal` elements as you can put on the page.

The methods [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) are supported by the major browsers and IE 8 and up. It works much like JQuery's selectors without the extra library.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$opRow['group_id']` is unique for each row, you'd start by doing

```
<button id="amend_<?php echo $opRow['group_id']; ?>" class="amend" value="<?php echo $opRow['group_id']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $opRow['group_id']; ?>">Amend</button>
```

and

```
<div id="modal_<?php echo $opRow['group_id']; ?>" class="modal">
```

Then in you Javascript/jQuery something like

```
$(".amend").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var theId = $(this).data("id");

    $("#modal_"+theId).show();
});

$(".close").on("click", function(e){
    // close any open modals
    $(".modal").each(function(){$(this).hide();});
    // if the modal element is the parent of the span
    $(this).parent().hide();
    // there's a few other options, such as targeting the id
});

$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if ($(event.target).hasClass("modal")) {
        // similarly there are multiple ways here to close the modals
        $(".modal").each(function(){$(this).hide();});
    }
});
```

[Basic Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lkedr26v/)

You may also want to look into using something like [jQueryUI's modal](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) as it packages up the styling and common things like close buttons all into one.